# Qemu cannot run Windows 11

Tags: windows, kvm-virtualization, qemu, tpm

When trying to execute the setup the setup stops after selecting the os type with the following result:

"this PC doesn't meet the minimum system requirements to install this version of windows. For more information visit ..."

What is wrong, My pc is up to date and Windows has enough memory?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So first of all win11 has 3 major system requirements

- 4GB RAM
- Secure boot
- TPM-device

The requirement of your hypersisor is qemu version 4. It is installed with Ubuntu 20.04.

### Secure Boot

We do need a secure "bios", which is an UEFI system. Using [Virtual machine Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Machine_Manager) you do only have one chance to set this setting up. In the last step 5 you are asked, if you want to do some additional modifications to your machine. Set that hook. Once the machine is created, you won't have an easy chance to change that!

- got to the tab `Overview`
- `Firmware` change the default `bios` to : `UEFI ... .secboot.fd`

### TPM device

The tpm thingy is a key management unit required by windows for security stuff.

*skip the ppa for >=22.04, just run install -> thx@Olaf*

If you not have installed `swtpm` yet, you have to install that on your machine.

```
https://launchpad.net/~smoser/+archive/ubuntu/swtpm 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:smoser/swtpm
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install swtpm-tools swtpm
```

Change the permission of that folder if necessary

```
sudo chown -R tss:root /var/lib/swtpm-localca
```

The tss user is used by qemu. In this folder will be the certificates.

Once installed, add the TPM-device to your machine. In the configuration window of the machine choose:

```
- [Add Hardware]
- TPM
  - `Model`:`CRB`
  - `Backend`:`Emulated device`
  - `Version`:`2.0`
```

With a bit of luck, you should now be able to pass the magical win11 install barrier.

Comment: Current Ubuntu (jammy, 22.04) already has swtpm (https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/swtpm), so ppa isn't required anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Just disable the Windows 11 requirements with `regedit`;

https://blogs.oracle.com/virtualization/post/install-microsoft-windows-11-on-virtualbox

- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> (run `cmd`)
- run `regedit`
- in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup`
- right-click `New`, `Key`, `LabConfig`
- `New`, `DWORD (32-bit)`, `BypassTPMCheck`, `1`
- same for `BypassRAMCheck` and `BypassSecureBootCheck`

Comment: This particular windows was used precisely for testing that feature.^^
Hacking was no option.
Does this also concern the bios check for secure boot?

Comment: @CuttonEye What are you asking about the "Bypass Secure Boot Check" option?